# Enzyme shallow dive fails with connected component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs, create-react-app

I try to test my connect component. Running this test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';

describe('Dashboard', () => {
  test('should render correctly according to the snapshot', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Dashboard />).dive();
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

According to [this](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1002) comment this should work but fails:

```
node_modules/subscriptions-transport-ws/node_modules/iterall/index.mjs:84
    export var $$iterator = SYMBOL_ITERATOR || '@@iterator'
    ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/subscriptions-transport-ws/dist/utils/empty-iterable.js:3:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/subscriptions-transport-ws/dist/server.js:8:24)
```

The dashboard is connected with `react-redux`'s `connnect` HOC:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  apolloLink: state.apollo.apolloLink,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: IMO you should not test connected components. Just export the container class and test it directly. But if you want to do it, use library like  this to mock store: https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store

Comment: +1 to @Moyote. What exactly you wnat to test? `Dashboard` component itself, or how it's working in combination with redux?
In first case, you need to import raw, not `connect`ed component to your tests.
In second case you need to mock store (as MEnf advises in his answer).
Anyway, I advise to read [official docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components)

Answer (score 1):

When testing a component that uses redux, you need to mock your store and provide it to your component before testing it.  You can use the "redux-mock-store" npm package to do so.

For Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

describe('Dashboard', () => {
  initialState = { apollo: { apolloLink: 'test value goes here' } }
  let store, wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(initialState)
    wrapper = shallow(<Dashboard store={store} />).dive()
  })

  it("Should render correctly according to snapshot", () => {
    let tree = wrapper.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```